# Trying to properly use ReactHook's useState

Tags: state, react-hooks

I want to establish some simple validation for my functional React component.  To that end, I'm using ReactHook's `useState` to instantiate a `validationErrors` object that is intended to grow like this:

```
{}
{'fieldName1': 'Some error message'}
{'fieldName1': 'Some error message', 'fieldName2': 'Another error message'}
{'fieldName1': 'Different error message', 'fieldName2': 'Another error message'}
```

```
  const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState(null);

  // If this function is working correctly then it will either add a
  // new key-value pair if the key doesn't exist yet or will update
  // the value if the key already exists.
  const updateValidationErrors = (name, error) => {
    if ([name] in validationErrors) {
      setValidationErrors({...validationErrors, [name]: error});
    } else {
      setValidationErrors({[name]: error, ...validationErrors});
    }
  };

  const checkValidation = (target) => {
    updateValidationErrors('companyName', 'Test Company 1');
    console.log(validationErrors);
    updateValidationErrors('companyName', 'Test Company 2');
    console.log(validationErrors);
    updateValidationErrors('notes', 'Notes error message 1');
    console.log(validationErrors);
    updateValidationErrors('notes', 'Notes error message 2');
    console.log(validationErrors);
    updateValidationErrors('companyName', 'Test Company 3');
    console.log(validationErrors);
  };
```

I'm getting strange results with the `console.log` and am wondering if that's because there is a short async delay with ReactHook's `useState`?

Or is there something wrong with my `updateValidationErrors` code?

Note: I tested the function here: https://repl.it/repls/WeeklyMustyMiddleware

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it won't work like this because in

```js
const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState(null);
```

`setValidationErrors` is nothing but the short hand of `setState({ validationErrors: <new value> })` which you have mentioned as well.

`setState` in react is an async call and doesn't guarantee that the value will be updated after the `setState` line is executed.

Try this to see the updated result

```js
  const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState();
  const updateValidationErrors = (name, error) => {
    setValidationErrors({...validationErrors, [name]: error});
  };

  const checkValidation = (target) => {
    updateValidationErrors('companyName', 'Test Company 1');
    updateValidationErrors('companyName', 'Test Company 2');
    updateValidationErrors('notes', 'Notes error message 1');
    updateValidationErrors('notes', 'Notes error message 2');
    updateValidationErrors('companyName', 'Test Company 3');
  };
```

Comment: I think that is not accurate. Did you try it and it work?

Comment: I don't see any issue but let me try it for you. Do you wanna share your whole component code?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Seems like there is no callback argument in hook like we have in `setState`. I will try to find out some ways to console it apart from using `useEffect` which is always return the last updated state.

Comment: But I guess you might have got your answer that your code will work fine, it's just console won't work immediately.

Comment: Yes I know, it just the console.. but else fine.
I'm actually use Redux with action reducer and state.
It will be interesting if you find another way :)

Comment: Yeah but unlucky. Seems like there is no way and people at the end agreed to go with `useEffect`. https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/issues/98

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback!  Related question: If I store something in a `Context API` object, I can see it by using the React Tools Chrome Extension.  However, I haven't been able to figure out how to look at a `useState` object in the same way.  Is this possible?

Comment: No as of now I don't think there is any tool to see the component level state. But you can do `console.log/alert` or put debugger to check the value.

Answer (score 0):

### react useState is not rective to console

react useState is not rective, then you can do useEffect to console.

And then you will see when validationErrorsupdate.

Add this line to your code

```
useEffect(() => console.log(validationErrors))
```

And of course

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "rective".  I've looked it up but it doesn't appear to exist.  What did you mean by this term?